# What’s difference between evaluate tag in view state or in action state

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I want to implement a transition to another view by call a function and set some variable in flow scope. Success or error event make no difference. I know, I can use evaluate tag for call function in both view state and action state. Is there any difference to put evaluate tag in each one? For this case which one is better?

Comment: It is better to use evaluate tag within action state and subsequently make the transition to another view state.View states are meant to have view specific details whereas action states are meant to evaluate a expression(method) to make the subsequent transition.

Comment: then when we use evaluate in view state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebFlow is flexible in the sense you can exec evaluate expression in any state via 'on-entry' and 'on-exit' tags or in the action-state tag. Like with any framework that allows for flexibility it is best to choose a strategy that is consistent through out all your flows. You could simply exec the evaluate expression inside a 'on-entry' or 'on-render' tag inside a 'view-state' but there is advantage to using an intermediary 'action-state' to exec your expressions there first then transition to 'view-state'.

**Advantage:**

Sometimes you have to evaluate multiple expressions but they are all part of the same 'action'. Grouping these multiple evaluations into and 'action-state' and providing the 'action-state' a meaningful id name can be helpful in flow readability and potential trouble shooting should an exception be thrown in that action-state.

So For instance,

Lets say we have to call 3 different service methods before we render a 'view-state'. We could do this:

```
<view-state id="myViewState" view="myViewFile" model="entity">
   <on-entry>
       <evaluate expression="myService.findObjById(id)" result="flowScope.model" />
       <evaluate expression="myService.updateUserStats(someField)"/>
       <evaluate expression="myService.performSomeOtherAction()"/>
   </on-entry>

</view-state>
```

and this would work just fine but it would be better if we removed all those service method calls from 'on-entry' and placed them in their own 'action-state' once finished executing then transition to the 'view-state'

```
<action-state id="prepareMyViewState">
       <evaluate expression="myService.findObjById(id)" result="flowScope.model" />
       <evaluate expression="myService.updateUserStats(someField)"/>
       <evaluate expression="myService.performSomeOtherAction()"/>
       <transition to="myViewState"/>
</action>

<view-state id="myViewState" view="myViewFile" model="entity">

</view-state>
```

Both of these example would be "correct" but the one with the action-state is more verbose and clearly defines the separation of concerns. So if an exception is thrown in the action-state 'prepareMyViewState' we know exactly what the role of this action-state from the name as oppose to the view-state 'myViewState' throwing the exception which could be related both the preparation or the rendering of the view-state. Also, in the future if you want to add/edit/remove service calls you can easily spot it in the flow file when they are placed in their own action-state with a meaningful name 'prepareMyViewState'.

Again, I would emphasize there are no wrong answers here I would just say pick a 'style' that is consistent throughout your entire web-flow application. The 2nd style with the intermediary action-state is the one I would use.